# SCSS divide operator not compiling

Tags: sass

I am using Sublime Text 2 and LiveReload to compile my `.scss` file. I also tried codekit with the same problem.

Using `+` and `-` work no problem, but `*` and `/` don't compile.

```
font-size: 30px / 2px; doesn't compile to font-size: 15px;
```

but

```
font-size: 30px + 2px; does compile to font-size: 32px;
```

Any ideas? The code hinting also doesn't seem to be working for the multiply and divide operators, could it be a package conflict? Seems unlikely.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Put it in parenthesis so SCSS understands you want it to do an arithmetic operation.  Also, you do not want to divide px by another px number as this will result in a unitless number.

This is what you are looking for:

```
div {
  font-size: (30px / 2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, worked perfectly. Why doesn't the documentation make note of that? http://sass-lang.com/guide.

Comment: It appears to now: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash

Comment: This link has changed now. New link: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Division_and__